# Conditional Python Typing for Generic Functions

Tags: python, typing

Assuming I have a class A and a derived class B:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

class A:
    type_field: Type[int] = int

class B(A):
    type_field: Type[str] = str
```

I want to have a function

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def func(object: T, some_field): 
    ...
```

A want `some_field` to be annotated (e.g. to show type hints) with type of T.type_field, assuming T derives from A or A itself. In other words, I want call `func(A(), ...` to suggest me passing `int` next, while call `func(B(), ...` should suggest passing string. Is there any way to achieve it in Python 3?

I want to develop a proper typing for function `def func` so developers get a proper type hint depending on the type of object passed first.

Comment: Beside the point, but `object` is a bad parameter name since there's already a [builtin `object`](//docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object). It'd be better to use something like `obj` or a more descriptive name if possible. You can [edit] to change it.

Comment: Could you make `A` generic, maybe with a corresponding abstract class property if you need the type at runtime?

Comment: Note that class B is not a proper class A. You cannot get this to work as shown because the premise is not type safe to begin with. Is B really required to inherit from A?

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html), which is afaik not possible in Python's type hinting system. So you'll have to rewrite this class to use generics if you want the type safety, as suggested by Samwise.

Answer (score 2):

This inheritance hierarchy is broken from the start. All instances of `A` are supposed to have a `type_field` attribute of static type `type[int]`, but instances of `B` are instances of `A` that do not satisfy this property. mypy will already complain, even before you try to write your `func`:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

class A:
    type_field: Type[int] = int

class B(A):
    type_field: Type[str] = str
```

[Output](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=e6fe537a453f357579bf787b699e2b3a):

```
main.py:7: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "type[str]", base class "A" defined the type as "type[int]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

That said, you can sort of write a function like what you want, with a potential caveat:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class FieldHaver(Protocol[T]):
    type_field: type[T]

def func(a: FieldHaver[T], b: type[T]):
    pass
```

The caveat is that `type` is covariant, so this will also accept any subtype of the type that `type_field` is annotated with. So these calls will work, like you want:

```
func(A(), int)
func(B(), str)
```

and this will fail (with a less helpful error message than you'd probably like):

```
func(B(), int)
```

but this will pass, which it sounds like you don't want:

```
func(A(), bool)  # bool is a subclass of int
```

I don't think there's any way around the covariance... although, if you don't want covariance, there's probably no point taking the second argument in the first place.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not really a caveat: you likely *don't want* a function that accepts `int` but rejects `bool` due to LSP, so it's a design flaw (yes, one may argue about difficult introspection cases, but those will confuse `mypy` anyway).